# How to create a custom keras generator to fit multiple outputs and use workers

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, eoferror

I have one input, and multiple outputs, like a multilabel classification, but I chose to try another approach to see if I have any improvements.

I have these generators, I'm using flow_from_dataframe because I have a huge dataset (200k):

```
self.train_generator = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=train,
    directory='dataset',
    x_col='Filename',
    y_col=columns,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    color_mode='rgb',
    class_mode='raw',
    shuffle=True,
    target_size=(HEIGHT,WIDTH))

self.test_generator = datatest.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=test,
    directory='dataset',
    x_col='Filename',
    y_col=columns,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    color_mode='rgb',
    class_mode='raw',
    target_size=(HEIGHT,WIDTH))
```

I'm passing to fit using this function:

```
def generator(self, generator):
    while True:
        X, y = generator.next()
        y = [y[:,x] for x in range(len(columns))]
        yield X,[y]
```

If I fit like this:

```
self.h = self.model.fit_generator(self.generator(self.train_generator),
    steps_per_epoch=self.STEP_SIZE_TRAIN,
    validation_data=self.generator(self.test_generator),
    validation_steps=self.STEP_SIZE_TEST,
    epochs=50,
    verbose = 1,
    workers = 2,
    )
```

I get :

```
RuntimeError: Your generator is NOT thread-safe. Keras requires a thread-safe generator when `use_multiprocessing=False, workers > 1`.
```

Using multiprocessing=True:

```
self.h = self.model.fit_generator(self.generator(self.train_generator),
    steps_per_epoch=self.STEP_SIZE_TRAIN,
    validation_data=self.generator(self.test_generator),
    validation_steps=self.STEP_SIZE_TEST,
    epochs=50,
    verbose = 1,
    workers = 2,
    use_multiprocessing=True,
    )
```

Results in:

```
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 877, in _run
    with closing(self.executor_fn(_SHARED_SEQUENCES)) as executor:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 867, in pool_fn
    pool = get_pool_class(True)(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 119, in Pool
    return Pool(processes, initializer, initargs, maxtasksperchild,
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 212, in __init__
    self._repopulate_pool()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 303, in _repopulate_pool
    return self._repopulate_pool_static(self._ctx, self.Process,
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 326, in _repopulate_pool_static
    w.start()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 327, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 93, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle 'generator' object


  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 877, in _run
    with closing(self.executor_fn(_SHARED_SEQUENCES)) as executor:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 867, in pool_fn
    pool = get_pool_class(True)(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 119, in Pool
    return Pool(processes, initializer, initargs, maxtasksperchild,
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 212, in __init__
    self._repopulate_pool()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 303, in _repopulate_pool
    return self._repopulate_pool_static(self._ctx, self.Process,
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 326, in _repopulate_pool_static
    w.start()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 327, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 93, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle 'generator' object

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 126, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

Now I'm stuck, how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/

The argument class_mode can be set as "multi_output" so you don't need to create a custom generator:

```
 class_mode: one of "binary", "categorical", "input", "multi_output", "raw", sparse" or None. Default: "categorical". Mode for yielding the targets: 

- "binary": 1D numpy array of binary labels, 
- "categorical": 2D numpy array of one-hot encoded labels. Supports multi-label output. 
- "input": images identical to input images (mainly used to work with autoencoders), 
- "multi_output": list with the values of the different columns, 
- "raw": numpy array of values in y_col column(s), 
- "sparse": 1D numpy array of integer labels, 
- None, no targets are returned (the generator will only yield batches of image data, which is useful to use in model.predict()).
```

I am now being able to use workers > 1, but I am not having performance improvements.